# Measure width() with jQuery after DOM refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, width, domready

My script dynamically creates a `<ul>` width left-floating `<li>`s inside: it's a paginator. Afterwards, the script measures width of all `<li>`s and summs them up.

The problem is that after the nodes are injected into the document — the browser refreshed DOM and applies CSS styles which takes a while. It has a negative effect on my script: when these operations are not complete before I measure the width — my script gets a wrong value. If I perform the measure in a second — everything is ok.

The thing I'm looking for is a way to detect the moment when the `<ul>` is fully drawn, styles applied and the width has stabilizes. Or at least a way to detect every dimensions changes. Of course I can use `setTimeout(..., 100)` but it's ugly and I guess — not a solution at all.

If there's a way to detect width stabilization — I would do the measuring right after it to get the correct values.

**HTML code generated by the DOM**

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="...">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="...">2</a></li>
        ....
        </ul>
    </div>
```

**P.S. Why I need this.** My paginator's left-floating `<li>` items tend to move to the next line when the `<ul>` tries to become wider than the page itself. Even though most of `<li>`s are invisible because of parent `<div>`'s width restriction:

```
div { width: 500px; overflow: hidden; }
div ul { width: 100%; white-space: nowrap; }
div ul li { display: block; float: left; }
```

they still go down unless I specify the actual summed width of the `<ul>` with the script.

Comment: Could you put some HTML code of what's generated by the DOM ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered that when I embed CSS into the document — everything's fine. This proves that the problem was my CSS files have not been loaded despite I used `$(document).ready()` for initializing.

One should use `$(window).load()` when relying on external resources and willing to measure widths correctly.